# How to make GROUP BY use index?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, group-by

I have a very simple query:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) sum, psp_id
FROM pos_transactions
GROUP BY psp_id
```

It takes over 10sec to be executed. Also here is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

Noted that, there is an index defined on `pos_transactions(psp_id)` as well. Any idea how can I make it optimal?

Comment: Have you tried using [force index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html#:~:text=The%20FORCE%20INDEX%20hint%20acts,As%20of%20MySQL%208.0.) ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: An index isn't going to be of much use for this sum query.  The reason is that your query has no `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses, but rather needs to iterate over the entire table.  MySQL might as well just scan the entire table once without the index.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the index should still avoid needing to create a temp table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So, any idea how can I make it faster to execute? You know, I have a similar query with `count(1)` instead of `sum(amout)`, and it is extremely fast.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Based on the result of `EXPLAIN`, I think the query is using an index as well. Just I don't know why it's pretty slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an index with both `psp_id` and `amount`:

```
create index psp_amount_ind on pos_transactions (psp_id, amount)
```

If you only have an index with `psp_id`, MySQL needs to fetch the `amount` from the row. Using an index in that case is not useful as it can also get the `psp_id` from the row.

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n0vBbhQo)

Comment: I did it, no difference .. [Even the `key_len` increased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxd6B.png)

Comment: @MartinAJ. See dbfiddle

Comment: Thanks Slaakso, upvoted, just by the fiddle you mean "Using index" in the "Extra" column?

Comment: @MartinAJ When the "Extra" column says "Using index" the whole query is executed against the index tree, no need to go through the data rows. This makes the query faster because the index size is smaller than the data in the data rows.